# Change size of Custom Excel Ribbon dropdown

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ribbon

[image]

I have this dropdown in the ribbon containing all the visible sheets in the workbook. Users can select a sheet in there to jump to it. It's important because there are a ton of sheets in this workbook. Unfortunately when the name of the sheet is long, it doesn't show completely. **I'd like to make it wider.**

I used the CustomUI Editor for Microsoft Office to create it using my not-very-fluent XML skills. Here is part of the code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="InitS3Ribbon">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="s3Tab" label="S3 Menu">
                <group id="grGeneral" label="General">

                    <dropDown id="navigation" label="Navigation" getItemCount="GetNavigateItemCount" getItemLabel="GetNavigateLabel" onAction="MenuNavigate" getSelectedItemIndex="SetNavigateIndex" showLabel="true" />

                    <button id="bShowHideSheet" imageMso="PivotPlusMinusButtonsShowHide" label="Show/Hide sheets" size="normal" onAction="MenuShowHideSheets" />
                    <button id="bPreviousPage" imageMso="LeftArrow2" label="Previous sheet" size="large" onAction="MenuPreviousSheet" />
                    <button id="bNextPage" imageMso="RightArrow2" label="Next sheet" size="large" onAction="MenuNextSheet" />
                </group>
```

I found [this resource](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2008/12/19/setting-the-width-of-a-drop-down-combo-box-or-edit-box-in-the-ribbon-designer-norm-estabrook/) saying that it can be changed with the [SizeString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbondropdown.sizestring.aspx) property but I'm not even sure how or where to include that in my code. Looks to me like it's supposed to be in the VBA section? I'm not sure I understand and I'd like guidance. I'm not sure whether to edit XML or VBA right now and how.

Comment: I haven't included the VBA portion because I feel like what I have right now doesn't really contribute, but I'll add anything if it can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official XML spec can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313070(v=office.12).aspx

It looks like sizeString can be used directly as an attribute to your dropdown XML tag. So something like:

```
<dropDown id="navigation" label="Navigation" sizeString="MY_MAX_LENGTH_STRING" getItemCount="GetNavigateItemCount" getItemLabel="GetNavigateLabel" onAction="MenuNavigate" getSelectedItemIndex="SetNavigateIndex" showLabel="true" />
```

You'll just have to know what the longest string you'll encounter will be, then put that in as `MY_MAX_LENGTH_STRING`. Considering you're using the dropdown to hold sheetnames, which are capped at 31 characters, you could probably use that length as a starting point.

Comment: Well this was simple... Thanks a lot!

Comment: ++ I posted an answer without refreshing and saw your answer :D. Had to delete mine... lol